# python packages installing order

Tags: pip, python-packaging

when we install python packages using pip, sometimes it installs some other packages. for example installing torch requires installing numpy. imagine in a requirements.txt file there are packages with their versions, but not in a right order. how can we realize the right order?
(for example if numpy version is specified as 1.1 but previous package in the list automatically installs numpy of last version!)

I installed librosa==0.9.2 which installed scipy 1.10 during its installation. but after that there is scipy=1.8 in the list. doesn't it make a conflict?

Comment: Is there some specific issue that you are encountering or are you just wondering about the process?

Comment: @sinoroc I just was wondering about the process and hopefully I didn't get an issue.

Comment: OK. So did I answer your question? Would you like to know more details? About what?

Answer (score 0):

Installation order should not matter at all if you use modern tools (Python, pip, etc.) and libraries that are packaged with modern techniques ([`[build-system]` section in `pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-build-dependencies/)).

In the case that you are presenting, it could be that *pip* had to build *librosa* (because no compatible *wheel* could be found). *pip* does builds in ephemeral one-time-use isolated virtual environments, so maybe *pip* used *scipy 1.10* to build *librosa*. But what was installed in your actual virtual environment was a different version of *scipy* (*1.8*), it is not an issue in itself. There are some cases, where a library is only compatible at run-time with the library it was built with.